# Show alert one below the other in Bootstrap + Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have my screen using `Bootstrap` and I want to show the alert messages one below the other. The problem is that I have one `CSS` class for all alerts that `AngularJS` repeats in the screen (I'm usign `ng-repeat` to show the error messages).

When I use `position: absolute` to show the alert on the top of the page, it's ok, but when the user do something that generates an error message, the alert is one under the other and I want to show one below the other.

My alert it's just like this:

```
<alert class="alert-position" ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg | translate}}</alert>
```

And my CSS class alert-position is:

```
.alert-position{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px!important;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any idea about how can I show this message one below the other, using `ng-repeat`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use directives like Notify (http://cgross.github.io/angular-notify/demo/) or Growl (https://github.com/marcorinck/angular-growl)?

Comment: Hi @JeremyThille thanks for this help... Actually I was trying to do it without any components, but I really enjoy this! :)

Comment: why not use Use angular bootstrap??

Comment: I'm using... The problem is that my page are injected on the body and I have to show the messages in top, that is my MasterPage... This are two separated files in my code...

Comment: can't you just wrap your repeated <alert> inside another div, and absolute position that div? everything inside the div will flow correctly.

Comment: @Joel the problem is if I create this DIV with absolute positioning, the user can use the another div's beside that...

Comment: @JeremyThille after implemented, the Angular Notify Component solved my problem... Thanks for this! :)

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for??

**PLNKR :**  http://plnkr.co/edit/o0jtVnLRpHXXukq5hANf?p=preview

**HTML :**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
  <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
  <button class='btn btn-default' ng-click="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**controller**

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('AlertDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.alerts = [
    { type: 'danger', msg: 'Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.' },
    { type: 'success', msg: 'Well done! You successfully read this important alert message.' }
  ];

  $scope.addAlert = function() {
    $scope.alerts.push({msg: 'Another alert!'});
  };

  $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
    $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
  };
});
```

Comment: Is exactly this, but the message have to be shown on the top, the problem is the I Inject the content of my page on a container...

Comment: Just to make the things clear, I have a Masterpage (that the messages have to appears) and I have a Angular Directive to inject the content of my page in my Body...

Comment: show the code please.post snippet.may be we can help you .

Comment: This is my plunker code: http://plnkr.co/edit/59kglp7UX9yokD8P0Dgb I want to show the alerts one below the other on the top of the page... Can I do this?

Comment: @LucasLira you can do that with the help of css.Logic remains the same.